# Simple way to numerically integrate constrained dynamics?

Tags: physics, numerical-methods

For example, a simple pendulum (string length = 1) can be described as

mx'' = λ*2x

my'' = -mg + λ*2y

x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0

where the primes mean derivatives w.r.t time, and λ*2x and λ*2y are the constraint forces coming from the 3rd equation, which is the constraint.

Of course, in this case, it is possible not to use λ by choosing the amplitude θ of the string as the only coordinate. In this case, I consider Python(Scipy)'s odeint would be the simplest free way to integrate the equations.

However, such coordinate reduction is not always easy.

Is there a simple way to integrate the constrained ODEs like this (without Mathematica/Maple/Matlab)? Neither performance nor accuracy is important to me, I just wont to quickly check the results.

(I'm not sure if this question suits here or the physics forum, but for me, it seems the physics forum is more of theory, but not very much about program and numerical stuffs.)

Your help is very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of systems is called differential-agebraic equation. There are standard solvers in netlib, DASSL for example.

One has to be careful to use the method that covers the (differentiation-)index of the DAE. Typically, solvers cover index-1 or index-2 systems. If the index is higher, one has to use symbolic index reducing methods before being able to apply numerical methods.

The pendulum has index 3, which means that the equations of the system have to be differentiated twice to be differentiated 3 times to be able to extract an ordinary system of differential equations. Or 2 differentiations to reduce to an explicit index-1 system.

Further reading: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Differential-algebraic_equations#Software

Comment: Wow!! This is exactly what I was asking. Even the examples are the same. I didn't know that such term exists. Thank you very much.